# Is this an ugly/incorrect usage of subscriptions?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

Little backstory: I'm trying to write code that will read messages from `INetworkConnection` that the `INetworkConnection` publishes and then send those up to the `NetworkController` which should do some processing and then send that off to an injected `IObserver<IMessage>` (which is a single observer because there's a global listener interested in network messages).

In other words, I'm trying to read messages, transform them, and then push them off to some listener. The reason why the controller is not subscribable is because there is only meant to be one listener (which will then distribute messages as necessary).

Now, right now I haven't added the transformation, so all the network controller does is that it pipes the messages from every connection into the injected subscriber like so:

```
    private readonly IDisposable _networkConnectionStreamSubscription;
    private readonly IObserver<INetworkMessage> _networkMessageStream;

    public NetworkController(IObservable<INetworkConnection> networkConnectionStream,
        IObserver<INetworkMessage> networkMessageStream)
    {
        _networkConnectionStreamSubscription = networkConnectionStream.Subscribe(
            x => LinkWith(x),
            () => Close());
        _networkMessageStream = networkMessageStream;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Link the Controller with the given Connection, allowing the network
    /// controller to start listening for network messages.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="networkConnection"></param>
    public void LinkWith(INetworkConnection networkConnection)
    {
        // Subscribe to the network message, and pipe the messages that have been parsed
        // out through our network message stream.
        // TODO: Do something with the subscription disposable
        networkConnection.Subscribe(
            x => _networkMessageStream.OnNext(x),
            exception => _NetworkMessageError(networkConnection, exception),
            () => _NetworkConnectionClosed(networkConnection)
        );
    }
```

My question is, simply speaking, am I

- going the wrong way by thinking of Rx as streams of T and
- is this considered an anti pattern/bad approach to what I am trying to do?

Comment: Is `_networkConnectionStreamSubscription` used at all?

Comment: Yes, that's used in the omitted `Dispose` method in order to unsubscribe the Disposed controller

Comment: I think it would be easier to review (with fewer assumptions) if you posted the whole class ;)

Comment: The only thing omitted here of value is actually the `Dispose` method. The other functions you see being referred to are empty methods, currently. I was wondering whether or not it would be considered bad practise to basically have a fall-through like I have with `_networkMessageStream`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think your approach is fundamentally wrong: Rx is all about exposing and responding to streams of data. I do wonder though if any of this is necessary; doesn't the [Observable.Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh244306%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) method do essentially what you are trying to do?